# syntactic function of word "if"

Tags: grammaticality

What syntactic function does the word "if" serves in this sentence.

> Certain pesticides can become ineffective **if** used repeatedly in the same place.

This sentence is taken from GMAC prep material so I am assuming that the sentence is grammatically correct.

According to oxford dictionary (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/if) the word if can only be a subordinate conjunction.However, there is no subject after if in the sentence above.

Moreover the first example sentence given by oxford dictionary for word if is

> if you have a complaint, write to the director.

but there is no main clause in this sentence.

So can the word if serve some other syntactic function also?

Comment: There a two 'if's - an _if_ of doubt (_what if...?_) and an _if_ of reason (_if this then that_).

Comment: Traditional grammar treats conditional "if" as a subordinating conjunction introducing, in this case, a non-finite clause. Like most non-finite clauses, it is subjectless, but the subject is _understood_ as "certain pesticides". However, more modern grammars treat conditional "if" as a preposition whose syntactic function is **head** of the preposition phrase that it introduces. In your last example the whole sentence is the main clause, with "write" as the 'main' verb. Whichever analysis is preferred, the conditional expression introduced by "if" functions as an adjunct, an optional element.

Comment: @BillJ And some of us modern linguists treat conditional *if* as a subordinator! (Well, my thesis argues it's one!)

Comment: @Araucaria You are (or were) courting martyrdom.

Comment: Doesn't that require multiple subtypes of prepositions to explain (or at least give names to) the various prepositional functions, such as "on the table" and "if used repeatedly"?

Comment: @TimR Less subtypes than you need for verbs or nouns, for example.

Comment: @Araucaria Is the non-finite clause considered the object of preposition **if**?

Comment: @TimR No, in the same way that *blue* isn't an object in *the sea is blue*. Complement but not object.

Answer (score 2):

BillJ commented:

> Traditional grammar treats conditional "if" as a subordinating conjunction introducing, in this case, a non-finite clause. Like most non-finite clauses, it is subjectless, but the subject is *understood* as "certain pesticides". However, more modern grammars treat conditional "if" as a preposition whose syntactic function is **head** of the preposition phrase that it introduces. In your last example the whole sentence is the main clause, with "write" as the 'main' verb. Whichever analysis is preferred, the conditional expression introduced by "if" functions as an adjunct, an optional element.

And Araucaria replied:

> And some of us modern linguists treat conditional if as a
> subordinator! (Well, my thesis argues it's one!)