# Is "when" considered a preposition in this sentence with extraposition and is the chunk an adjunct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjuncts, extraposition

I recently discovered that [**if** is considered a preposition in contemporary grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515859/syntactic-function-of-word-if?noredirect=1#comment1563780_515859). Is "when" considered a preposition as well? And in the following sentence, is the chunk introduced by **when** considered an *adjunct*, or as integral in that it provides the referent for "it"?

> I like it when you say "indubitably".

Comment: The same modern grammar classifies "when" as a preposition. In your example, the PP _when you say "indubitably"_ has a paraphrase containing noun + integrated relative: _I like it on those occasions when you say "indubitably"_.

Comment: In object extraposition the "it" is a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the object position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.  Btw, extraposition of PPs is controversial. Some grammars say that PPs cannot be extraposed.

Comment: @BillJ  I wasn't aware of the controversy but that was indeed the question that came into my mind.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: On reflection, although your example does bear some resemblance to extraposition inasmuch as what I like is your saying "indubitably", it differs from extraposition in that the final element is not a content clause, not a potential replacement for "it".

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, what I'm saying is that your example does not in fact contain extraposition.

Comment: Is this extraposition?  *I like it that you say "indubitably"*.

Comment: Yes: I would say it is. In fact it's obligatory here since "like" does not license a content clause on its own, at least not in BrE.

Comment: @BillJ  I didn't know that.  This is marginal or ungrammatical in BrE:  "I like that it gets good mileage"  ?

Comment: It sounds awful to me. H&P's Cambridge Grammar says simply that it's ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ  How about "I appreciate that it gets good mileage"?

Comment: Or to remove "get" which might be coloring things:  I appreciate that it's fuel-efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If

This depends on the framework. It's definitely not universally considered a preposition even in modern model-theoretic syntax (Sag, Wasow, Bender 2003, Borsley 2019). But the conditional *if* is indeed taken to be a preposition in *CGEL* (2002), a major descriptive grammar.

There are two other *if*'s in the English language: the interrogative subordinator and a more exotic irrealis subordinator (Pullum 1988, Rocchi 2010):

(1) *I wonder if it's true.*  — *if* as an interrogative subordinator

(2) *Imagine if it were true!* — *if* as an irrealis subordinator

### When

*When* is exclusively a preposition in *CGEL*, although a problematic one, because it forms two subtly different constructions: fused relative preposition phrases (similar to most uses of *where*) and regular PPs with *when* as the head and a content clause as a complement (similar to the conditional *if*, as well as *since*, *because* and *although*). Both constructions function as adjuncts in the following examples:

(3) *When they come, call Jane.* — *when they come* if a fused PP

(4) *When they weren’t home at six o’clock, I began to get worried.* — *when* is a preposition taking a content clause complement; example due to Huddleston & Pullum 2002 (p. 1078)

But as Rocchi 2010 (p. 46) shows (Pullum & Reynolds 2013 concur), *when*, just like *if*, might have become a subordinator as well. They use an example similar to yours:

(5) *I hate (it) when people say that learning Latin teaches you to be logical.*

This construction is closely related to the irrealis *if* both semantically and grammatically. The *when*-phrase here is not an adjunct, but a complement, similar to phrases with *if* in (1) and (2). For example, like the "third *if*" and unlike regular *when*-adjuncts, it resists preposing:

(6) **When people say that learning Latin teaches you to be logical, I hate.*

Irrealis *if* tends to occur in extraposed clauses, but with this *when*, extraposition is not necessary: you can remove *it*, and the sentence is still grammatical.

[Pullum and Reynolds](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/ClosedClasses.pdf) give some more examples of what they believe is the new subordinator *when*, featuring verbs like *love*, *hate*, *like* and *regret*.

---

Borsley, Robert D. 2019. Phrase structure. In *The Oxford Handbook of English Grammar*

Huddleston, Rodney & Geoffrey K. Pullum *et al.* 2002. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*

Rocchi, Manuela. 2010. A third *if*?

Pullum, Geoffrey K. 1988. Implications of English extraposed irrealis clauses

Pullum, Geoffrey K. & Brett Reynolds. 2013. New members of 'closed classes' in English

Sag, Ivan A., Thomas Wasow & Emily M. Bender. *Syntactic Theory: A Formal Introduction*

Comment: Thanks.  How about "Go right ahead. See if  *I* care!"  ?  How would that **if** be categorized?

Comment: @TimR That's just an interrogative subordinator.

Comment: That's good.  Just looking for familiar *terra firma*  :-)